# Dimension Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

The question asked is whether the following statement is true:

> Let $W$ be a two-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$. Then two of the following three vectors span $W: X = [1,0,0]^t, Y = [0,1,0]^t, Z = [0,0,1]^t$.

I think the answer is that it is false because it is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ and thus needs 3 vectors. However, we can only choose $2$. Therefore, it is false. Is this line of reasoning correct? If so, then what is the utility of the "two dimensional subspace" part?

Thanks!

Comment: If $\textrm{dim}(W) = 2$, then you need at least $2$ vectors to span $W$.

Comment: So you are saying its true?

Comment: basis of $\mathbb R^3$ needs $3$ vectors; basis of a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ such as {$(x,y,0)$} needs $2$

Comment: Since all the 3 are independent, any 2 would span W then. Does that mean that the statement is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building off the current answers, there are exactly three subspaces that can be formed with two of the vectors $X, Y, Z$. In particular, if you choose $W = \text{span}(X, Y)$ then $W$ contains points of the form $$x(1, 0, 0) + y(0, 1, 0) = (x, y, 0).$$ Similarly, if you choose $X, Z$ (resp. $Y, Z$) then $W$ contains points of the form $(x, 0, z)$ (resp. $(0, y, z)$). So the question is whether there are subspaces $W$ containing points not of this form.

One way to show, other than the explicit method of finding a counterexample, is to note $W$ is a (hyper)plane in $\mathbb R^3$. (A hyperplane in $\mathbb R^n$ is a subspace of dimension $n-1$.) This means that $$W = \{(x, y, z) \mid a_1x + a_2y + a_3z = 0\}$$ is the solution space to some linear equation $a_1x + a_2y + a_3z = 0$ with at least one of $a_1, a_2, a_3$ nonzero. The three subspaces above correspond to $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ equal to $(0, 0, 1)$, $(0, 1, 0)$ and $(1, 0, 0)$ respectively, but there are clearly far more choices of $a_1, a_2, a_3$ than just these three. In fact, the possibilities are parameterised by points on the sphere $S^2 \subset \mathbb R^3$ so in particular, there are (uncountably) infinitely many $2$-dimensional subspaces but the number of subspaces we can make with two of $X, Y, Z$ is $3$.

Comment: But since either of the two vectors chosen have a 1 in different coordinates (for example (1,0) and (0,1) , won't their scalar multiples span the entire 2 Dimensional subspace? I mean that whatever choice a1,a2, and a3 be, they will be some scalar multiple of (1,0) and (0,1)

Comment: If I understand the question: you say the scalar multiples of any two of $X, Y, Z$ will span "the" entire 2-dimensional subspace, but the point is that "the" 2-dimensional subspace is wrong since there is in fact "many" 2-dimensional subspaces; we just saw three different subspaces, containing respectively points of the form $(x, y, 0)$, $(x, 0, z)$ and $(0, y, z)$. So what I'm saying is there are some choices of $a_1, a_2, a_3$ such that $W$ contains points that are not linear combinations of, say, $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant. From what I learnt in class, if the dimension equals the elements in the set (which it does, as we are free to choose any 2 vectors for a 2 Dimensional subspace) and that the 2 vectors are linear independent (which they are ), then they would span the entire subspace. Maybe the answer to this question will clear my doubts: is there any 2 vectors (not necessarily from the options in the question) that span the entire subspace?

Comment: Right, as Ethan said, if $W$ is $2$-dimensional then any $2$ vectors in $W$ that are linearly independent would span $W$. For the last part of your question: yes; there **will** exist $2$ such vectors, since this is a part of the definition of $W$ being $2$-dimensional. But the point is that these $2$ vectors, **which are in $W$**, might not be $X, Y, Z$. For instance, if $W$ is the span of $(1, 1, 1)$ and $(1, 1, 2)$, then neither of these vectors can be written as a linear combination of two of $X,Y,Z$. By the way, this is the subspace of points of the form $(x, x, z)$ with $x, z$ arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

A two dimensional subspace will be spanned by two linearly independent vectors *in the subspace*.

Can you think of any two dimensional subspaces that don't contain any of those three vectors? For an analogy: can you think of any lines through the origin (one dimensional subspaces) in the two dimensional plane that don't contain the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$?

Comment: the y=x line maybe?

Comment: @gazillionTickets Yes. Now you should be able to build many counterexamples to answer your original question.